# decrement background position css with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to run an animation by altering the `background-position` of an image within a `div`. I'm using `setTimeout` to recall the function and continuously decrement the image position (so it appears to be animated). I've tested the the variables and `setTimeout` they seem to be working fine. The image however is not moving at all.

How can i amend the code to enable this animation to run ?

```
var decrement = 0;

function runningRobot() {
var robotCont = document.getElementById('robotCont');

  if(decrement < -660) {
  decrement = 0;
}
 robotCont.style.backgroundPositon = decrement+ 'px' +' '+ 0 + 'px';
decrement -= 110;  
timer = setTimeout(runningRobot,500);
}

runningRobot();
```

Comment: I think you don't need to concatenate zero. Should be `decrement+ 'px  0px'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled backgroundPosition:

```
robotCont.style.backgroundPosition = decrement + 'px' + ' ' + 0 + 'px';
```

I also don't know if you'll need the position left setting.  I think 0 is the default, and since it comes second to top, it can be omitted, right?

```
robotCont.style.backgroundPosition = decrement + 'px';
```

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position), the `background-position` style needs "a list, each item consisting of two keywords". The second `0px` can't be omitted. Also, you can reduce the `decrement + 'px' + ' ' + 0 + 'px'` code to `decrement + 'px 0px'`. I'll upvote after you've made those changes.

Comment: Not embarrassing. Normal.

Answer (score 0):

To improve to axiom82's answer, you can also reduce your code by putting the amount of seperate parts you have together. You'd change it **from**:

```
robotCont.style.backgroundPosition = decrement + 'px' + ' ' + 0 + 'px';
```

**to**:

```
robotCont.style.backgroundPosition = decrement + 'px 0px';
```

as was also suggested by antyrat in the comments.

And to correct axiom82, it is not allowed to omit the second `0px`, as can be seen on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position), which says the `background-position` style needs "a list, each item consisting of two keywords". This means both the `x` and the `y` need to be specified, and the second value can't be omitted.

Comment: Thanks, Joey. It was more of a quick idea when I mentioned the partial position value. Have you tested the partial value in browsers yet. MSDN is not necessarily the authority. W3C is more widely accepted. I haven't had the time to check their standards on background position values.

Comment: @MichaelMcNally MDN directly takes their information from sources such as W3C standards, so usually they are right about this kind of thing. The advantage of checking MDN is that they usually put it in an easier layout, so it's easier to find the thing you're looking for there. By the way, it's MDN (Mozilla Developer Network), not MSDN (MicroSoft Developer Network)